# Usage about "interpret...as..."

Tags: word-usage

For example, a guy followed my advice for him on learning English and he can now effectively communicate with people in English though not that great in terms of pronunciation, grammar, etc. While in the past he just could barely make any conversation with people in English. In that situation, which one of these two sentences in question is better?

> I interpret his present performance as he has succeeded with his English learning.

or

> I interpret his present performance as him having succeeded with his English learning.

Comment: "it" here is a ***thing*** (i.e. - a ***noun***). So it's more natural to interpret / treat / refer to it using a noun phrase such as ***him having made it***, rather than a verb-based "statement" such as ***he has made it***. But strictly speaking, it should probably be *I interpret it as **evidence of** him having made it*, because that's what you *really* mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I want to make sure I've precisely gotten my points cross. Actually, I wanted to express in that situation that he has already succeeded with learning English after follwing my advice since he can effectively communicate in English although still not that great with pronunciation,grammar,etc. In that case, which of those two sentences in question is better?

Comment: I don't think there are a range of possible different meanings here, so I can't see any reason why you should be concerned about "precisely getting your point across". That's to say, there's no ***semantic*** issue here. But as pointed out before, "it" (and what it refers to, "his present performance") are ***things*** (nouns), and stylistically I think it's better to interpret one "thing" as another thing (the "state, condition" of "him having made it") rather than comparing a thing to a statement "He has made it"). But I already said all that, so I'm just repeating myself.

Comment: Thanks, FumbleFingers. Thank you for your elaborate answer.  I think I have a quite deeper understanding about my question now.

Comment: The important thing is both your suggested sentences are perfectly okay as they stand. But if I was being "picky", I'd say the first one should really be slightly amended to *I interpret his present performance as **meaning [that]** he has succeeded with his English learning.* That's to justify a "verb-based interpretation" - alternatively, stick with noun phrases throughout and go for *...interpret his present performance as **evidence that** he has succeeded*. This is just "style advice" though, so it's not particularly important (and not all native speakers will share *my* perspective! :)).

Comment: Thanks, FumbleFingers. So you  don't think the first  sentence I suggested has any grammatical problems apart from some stylistic ones?

Comment: I'm not really interested in "grammatical correctness" at this level, but I'm sure all strict grammarians would agree your first sentence isn't syntactically valid. Though to be honest, I'd be surprised if *any* "strict" grammarians would accept the second version as valid either (unless you include something like *...interpret it as **evidence for** him having done something* as per my previous comments). Your text is "okay" because even native speakers mangle languasge like that sometimes. But it's not syntactically sensible.

Comment: Thanks,  FumbleFingers. You've made a good point to me. Really appreciate it. I've a broader and clearer picture about the "issues" related to my question now.  I feel it's a great feeling. Just keep going, right? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to run a few searches against the Google Books corpus, for text sequences like ["I interpret this as"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+interpret+this+as%22). You'll see that it's very common to follow that one with a continuous verb form such as ***...as meaning / indicating / demonstrating / ...*** You probably won't find many ***statements*** (incl. subject + "tensed" verb, as ***...he has succeeded***), but you might well find *some* instances phrased like. But that kind of "sloppy" syntax is far more common in speech that writing, obviously.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate that, FumbleFingers

Comment: FumbleFingers,  could you please tell me whether it's ok or better if I replace "performance" with "ability" in my suggested sentences? Thank you.

Comment: My personal feeling is that they are basically interchangable in that context, is that right?

Comment: "performance" and "ability" mean different things, as I'm sure you either already know or can easily establish by looking the words up in a dictionary. But in practice I don't suppose it makes any difference which you use in the cited example context (or you could use something different, such as ***level***; it doesn't really matter).

Comment: Thanks you very much, Fumblefimgers, good point.